# Shift register, connecting wired inputs to internal register

Tags: verilog

Here is my module

```
module shift(
input clk,
input rstn,
input load, 
input dir,
input [7:0] LD,
output cout
);

reg [7:0] mem;

assign cout = dir?mem[0]:mem[7] ;


always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn)
begin
 if(!rstn)
  mem <= 8'h00;
 else begin
  if(load) 
   mem <= LD ;
  else mem <= mem ;
  case(dir)
   0 : mem <= mem<<1 ;
   1 : mem <= mem>>1 ;
  endcase
 end
end

endmodule
```

and here is my testbench.

```
module shift_tb();

reg clk;
reg rstn;
reg load;
reg dir;
reg[7:0] LD ;
wire cout;

shift UUT(.clk(clk), .rstn(rstn), .load(load), .dir(dir), .LD(LD), .cout(cout));

initial begin

$dumpfile("shift_out.vcd");
$dumpvars(2,shift_tb);

 clk = 0 ;
 rstn = 0 ;
 load = 0;
 dir = 0 ;
 LD = 8'h00;
 
 #10;
 rstn = 1;

 LD = 8'h55 ;
 load = 1;
 dir = 0 ;

 #100;

 LD = 8'hAA ;
 load = 1;
 dir = 1;

 #100;
 
 LD = 8'hFF;
 load = 1;
 rstn = 0 ;
 
 #20 ;
 $finish;
end 

always 
 #5 clk = ~clk ;

endmodule
```

In the above code, my internal register "mem" does not take in the values from "LD" (parallel i/p ).

It stays at 0. The code does shift if `mem` is initialized with a random value say 8'h22 but still doesn't take in `LD`.

This contains the waveform
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple *active* nonblocking assignments to `mem`; only one should be active at any given time.  After reset, you have `load`=1 and `dir`=0.  This means your code first assigns `mem <= LD` then immediately assigns `mem <= mem<<1`.  You must not do that.  Your code has the `case` in parallel with the `if` statement.  Perhaps you intended the `case` to be inside the `else` clause.

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn)
        mem <= 8'h00;
    else begin
        if(load) 
            mem <= LD ;
        else
            case(dir)
                0 : mem <= mem<<1;
                1 : mem <= mem>>1;
            endcase
    end
end
```

When I run the sim, I see `mem` change to `'h55`, as expected.

In this case, you just need to pulse `LD` high for one cycle in your testbench, instead of keeping it high all the time:

```
 LD = 8'h55 ;
 load = 1;
 dir = 0 ;

 #10;
 load = 0;

 #100;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have used a very verbose logic. Try this..

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn)
begin
if(!rstn)
  mem <= 8'h00;
else 
 mem <= (load)?LD:( dir ? mem>>1 : mem<<1 ); 
end
```

In your tb use this. Transition rst as 1->0->1. Keep LD and load stable for 1 clock
cycle. Then de-assert load.

```
initial
begin
 clk = 1'd0;
 rst = 1'd1;
 load = 1'd0;
 dir = 1'd0;
 LD  = 'd0;

 #10  rst = 1'd0;
 #100 rst = 1'd1;
    load = 1'd1;
    LD = 8'h55;
 #10 load = 1'd0;

 end
```